# How to quickly check if a Hermitian matrix has a zero eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A Hermitian matrix $A$ has real eigenvalues. One way to check if it has a zero eigenvalue is to compute the determinant $\mathrm{det}(A)$. If $\mathrm{det}(A) = 0$, then  $A$ has an eigenvalue of zero. However, computing the determinant, just as computing the eigenvalues, is a computationally expensive process.

A Hermitian matrix $A$ also has real diagonal entries. Is there any way to make use of this fact or other properties of a Hermitian matrix to quickly check if $A$ has an eigenvalue of zero?

Comment: Are you looking for a numerical/computer algorithm, or are you looking for a "pencil and paper" method?

Comment: For "most" Hermitian matrices, one could [compute a decomposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4504209/81360) $A = LDL^*$ with $L$ lower-triangular with 1's on the diagonal and $D$ diagonal. We then have $\det(A) = \det(D)$, which is fast to compute.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I am looking for a "pencil and paper" method.